# How to write this regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Consider the language over the alphabet $\sum= \{a\}$ containing strings whose length is either a multiple of 2 or 3 (including the empty strings). Writing a regular expression for this language

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? I answered one of your questions that was similar to it which you posted not long ago - This isn't a place for you to copy paste homework questions for solutions.

Comment: So far I have $(a) \ast$ but this would be a regexp for strings of length 0 or strings of the form a,aaa, aaaa etc. How would one factor in the string length being a multiple of 2 or 3

Comment: See Yuval's hint below - You should be able to derive a solution with the hint he provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A number $n$ is a multiple of $2$ or $3$ if $n \; \mathrm{mod} \; 6 \in \{0,2,3,4\}$.

Simpler solution: Take the union of the words whose length is a multiple of 2 with the words whose length is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Based on this hint, would this be correct $(aa)^\ast |(aaa) ^\ast$